# mapbox android setStyle callback not calling

Tags: android, mapbox-android

thanks in advance,

My android mapbox suddenly stops working , when i debug i see that setStyle callback is not triggered. It just show up a blank activity with no map.
The `OnStyleLoaded` callback never trigger.
This was working fine for me few weeks back.

I tried changing the token and still having the issue.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS, style -> {
            enableLocationComponent();
            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap);
        });
}
```

the callback function is not being called.

Could anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with the VPN.
As i was using a VPN app my map-box calls were not going through.
So if anyone had this issue make sure map-box api call is succeeded.